# Korean movie with ghost on man's shoulders

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to find a movie I saw a few years ago, and I don't remember much about it so I hope someone will find with the few information I have

It's an asian ghost movie, a Korean movie I think, about a guy and his girlfriend. A lot of weird things happen to the guy, and the ghost who does that is (I think, I hope i'm not mixing different movies) a girl that used to love him, but that used to be bullied by him and his group of friends.

During all the movie, the guy has back pain and at a moment, he goes up on a scale and seems to weigh way too much.

In the end of the movie, he realizes that the ghost of the girl has been sat on his shoulders all along.

I know that's few information but I don't remember more than this, and since I saw this movie when I was younger and it scared me, I'd like to see it again now !

Comment: "I don't remember more than this, and since I saw this movie when I was younger." and "a movie I saw a few years ago." ...

Comment: I was younger a few years ago :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it's Thai, not Korean. This sounds like [Shutter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0440803/combined) from 2004. From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_%282004_film%29):

> Tun begins to discover mysterious white shadows and what appear to be faces in his photographs. A suspicious Jane thinks these images may be the ghost of the girl they hit on the road. Tun, who has been experiencing severe neck pains since the accident, visits a specialist. While a nurse attempts to measure his weight, to his dismay, he weighs approximately 120 kilograms (264 pounds).

It has been remade twice, as [Click](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_%282010_film%29) (2010) in India and as [Shutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_%282008_film%29) (2008) in the US. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Yep looks like it might be this one.
I watched the trailer yesterday but was not sure as I didn't find anything about the weight, but with your answer I'm pretty sure that's the right movie.
However I must have been mixing with another movie for the bullying story.
Thanks !

Comment: No, that part fits too. He was in a relationship with the girl and dumped her before they ran her over. Anyway, glad you found it!

Comment: @ Florian.C May be you're confused with the US version released in 2008. It has a scene where the guy takes a weight check and the nurse beside to him is surprised looking at the scale that he weighs too much and asks him to step down and check the weight again.